# Default value displaying when textbox is empty

Tags: javascript

I have on load event default values for several text fields. However, when any of the text fields is edited and made blank after it submitted the default values reappear. How do I make it that if its empty by the user that it remains empty after submission?

Comment: you said javascript: post some code so we can see what you're doing and if you're doing the right thing?

Answer (score 1):

By default value, do you mean the value in the value atttribute? If so, the value attribute doesn't specify the default value, it specifies the current value period. If you don't want it to be displayed, set it to an empty string.

Alternatively, you can use the html5 placeholder attribute which will disappear when the text box gets focus.

Comment: That's not technically true: the initial value of a form field is defined by the value attribute. The value _attribute_ should never change, but the element's value _property_ can. See the [w3c spec on form fields](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.2).